# How to get the last letter of a word or string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to take a pet name from the user which ends with the letter y if the user enters the name Sammy so it should print that you enter the right name otherwise nothing. But when I enter this name, Sammy

```
var petName=prompt("Enter your pet name?")
var x=petName.length-1
alert("index number of last latter is: "+x)
if(petName[x]=="y"){
   
   console.log("You have entered the right name.")    
}
```

first, it showing in the alert dialog the following message

the index number of the last latter is: NoN

second if the statement is not executing.

Comment: `.lenght` should be `.length`. Also your closing brace is an opening brace, but that's probably not in the actual code you're running, otherwise you'd not get any alerts.

Comment: sorry In the editor it was right like length and the closing brace was also correct but still it  giving the same output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just mistyped length as lenght. Everything else is fine, good job!

Answer (score 2):

Your almost there. Just have to change the .lenght to .length:

```
var petName=prompt("Enter your pet name?")
var x=petName.length-1
alert("index number of last letter is: "+x)
if(petName[x]=="y"){
   
   console.log("You have enter the right name.")    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = "ctl03_Tabs1";
id.substr(id.length - 1);//get the last character
id.substr(2);//get the characters from the 3rd character on
id.substr(2, 1);//get the 3rd character
id.substr(2, 2);//get the 3rd and 4th characters
```